# Считывание с файла. С++

Tags: c++, файлы, дата

Почему появляется эта ошибка? Когда я не использую `!file2.eof`, ошибка не возникает.

**Ошибка**: *Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x7673B727 в Проект1.exe: исключение Microsoft C++: std::bad_alloc по адресу памяти 0x002AF43C.*

Вот код:

```
class foo
{
    string Name;
    int Age;
    public:
    foo() : Name(" "), Age(0){}
    foo(string name, int age) : Name(name), Age(age){}

    void set_p()
    {
        cout << "Enter Name: ";
        cin >> Name;
        cout << "Enter Age: ";
        cin >> Age;
    }

    void show()
    {
        cout << "Name: " << Name << endl;
        cout << "Age: " << Age << endl;
    }
    void write(ostream& os)
    {
        os.write((char*)&Age, sizeof(Age)); // Запись POD-члена
        size_t len = Name.length() + 1;       // Длина с нулевым байтом
        os.write((char*)&len, sizeof(len)); // Запись длины
        os.write((char*)Name.c_str(), len);  // Запись данных
    }

    void read(istream& in)
    {
        in.read((char*)&Age, sizeof(Age));   // Чтение POD-члена
        size_t len;                         // Переменная для длины
        in.read((char*)&len, sizeof(len));  // Чтение длины записанной строки
        char * buf = new char[len];         // Выделение буфера для чтения
        in.read(buf, len);                   // Чтение (с нулевым байтом)
        Name = buf;                         // Присвоение считанной строки члену
        delete[]buf;                        // Освобождение памяти
    }
};

int main()
{
    foo obj("Oleh", 20);
    foo obj2;

    ofstream file;
    file.open("file.bin", ios::binary );
    obj.write(file);
    obj.set_p();
    obj.write(file);
    file.close();

    ifstream file2;
    file2.open("file.bin", ios::binary);
    file2.seekg(0);
    while (!file2.eof())
    {
        obj2.read(file2);
        obj2.show();
    }
    file2.close();

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

По-моему, эта ошибка - самая распространенная в SO...

```
while (!file2.eof())
```

Так делать **НЕЛЬЗЯ**.
Потому что признак конца файла выставляется **ПОСЛЕ** неудачного чтения!
Только после того, как была неудачная попытка что-то прочесть за концом файла - только тогда `eof()` вернет `true`.

**Update**
Вот вариант:

```
bool read(istream& in)
{
    int tAge;
    in.read((char*)&tAge, sizeof(tAge));   // Чтение POD-члена
    size_t len;                         // Переменная для длины
    in.read((char*)&len, sizeof(len));  // Чтение длины записанной строки
    char * buf = new char[len];         // Выделение буфера для чтения
    in.read(buf, len);                   // Чтение (с нулевым байтом)
    if (in)                             // read OK
    {
        Name = buf;                         // Присвоение считанной строки члену
        Age = tAge;
    }
    delete[]buf;                        // Освобождение памяти
    return !!in;
}
```

Функция возвращает `true` только когда все успешно считано. При сбоях она не только возвращает `false`, но и ничего не пишет в объект - он остается в том же состоянии, что и до чтения (обеспечение транзакции - или все, или ничего; для этого и читаем сначала в `tAge`).

Ну, а цикл имеет вид:

```
while (obj2.read(file2))
{
    obj2.show();
}
```

Comment: А как тогда узнать конец файла?

Comment: См. дополненный ответ